# “Continue reading” not on some posts, full excerpts not shown

Tags: excerpt, read-more

*Crossposted from [my topic on wordpress.org forum](https://wordpress.org/support/topic/continue-reading-not-on-home-page-post-excerpts-not-all-before-more-block/) since I don't seem to be getting any bites*

Hi there!
I’m fairly new to WordPress, my website is https://slasheethecow.com and I’m trying to be a smartarse but there’s a certain post I can’t get to show a “Continue reading” link on the home page for a post, [this post](https://slasheethecow.com/2021/10/24/windows-11-review-preview/) to be specific.

Originally the post was just a couple of paragraphs of text, then a more block, then an image, and I can’t for the life of me figure out what’s wrong with it. You’d have to click on the post’s title to see it all. I’m using the Twenty Twenty-One theme with a few CSS changes, and I've tried about all I can think of:

- Disabled CSS changes
- Disabled all plugins (didn’t help, actually they’re all still disabled, guess it shows how much I need them).
- Tried recreating the post from scratch (nada).

For a test I made a lorem ipsum post, and it contains two paragraphs of text, then a more block, then a few more paragraphs of text. It does get an excerpt and a “continue reading” on the homepage, but the excerpt *isn’t all that’s before the more block*, just what I’m assuming is the automatically generated excerpt, and is much shorter than the text before the more block. So I guess I found another problem trying to fix one.

Back to the original post, (the one with the Simpsons meme) I tried adding lorem ipsum next both before and after the more block and the image block on the post (both before and after the image), but still no “continue reading” link on the home page. I also tried changing the “post format” option to a few different ones, none of them showed the read more link.

Is there something I’m missing? Is it not designed to handle my unique brand of writing? Did I trigger an exceptional use case? Please help me. I’m at my wit’s end (and by that I mean my wit wishes to end up in peoples’ faces) and I’ve tried searching a zillion different terms and can’t find any fixes that apply to WordPress in general, most are a problem with a specific plugin or theme.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: what setting are you using under 'Customize' - 'Excerpt Settings'? are you using a hand-written excerpt for the post? have you asked in the theme's forum at https://wordpress.org/support/theme/twentytwentyone/ ?

Comment: @Michael Thanks! It was under "Customise > Excerpt Settings". I guess I misinterpreted the options, thinking "Full text" would display the whole post, not just the whole whatever was before the more block. You wanna submit that as an answer so I can give you a nice tick?